# How to include entire folder in TypeScript build?

Tags: typescript

I have a `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6"
      ],
      "target": "es6",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "strict": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "removeComments": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "strictFunctionTypes": true,
      "noImplicitThis": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true
   },
   "exclude": ["node_modules"],
   "include": [
     "./src/**/*.ts",
     "./src/customer-api-docs/*"
    ]
}
```

I have a folder called `customer-api-docs` that I want included in its entirety as part of the build (it contains static files for use by a library called [Docsify](https://docsify.js.org/#/).

I have added `"./src/customer-api-docs/*"` as part of the `include` property, and additionally I have also tried without the trailing `/*`. However when running `tsc -b` the folder is not within the build folder. All the other ts files are successfully compiled to the build folder though.

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give!

Answer (score 3):

if someone has arrived here wanting to include any folder in the typescript build folder, here is one approach.

You can just use an npm module copyfiles to copy all the folders you want in your build folder. I was deploying a heroku app built on typescript server and Reactjs. I wanted my client folder to be included in the build. So, I added this script:

```
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix src/client && npm run build --prefix src/client&&copyfiles src/client/*/ build",
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking up in TypeScript [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) I found out that you actually allowed to include non-ts files into your build

> If a glob pattern doesn’t include a file extension, then only files with supported extensions are included (e.g. .ts, .tsx, and .d.ts by default, with .js and .jsx if allowJs is set to true).

So probably setting something like this may help (docsify):

```
{
  "include": [
     "./src/**/*.ts",
     "./src/customer-api-docs/*.html",
     "./src/customer-api-docs/*.md"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Thanks for the link to the docs, your suggestion definitely seems to heading in the right direction, unfortunately it still doesn't seem to copy the folder. Is there any possibility it might not be using the right tsconfig? Do you have to pass the config to the build command or "refresh" it somehow? Thanks again